# Remove Addins - AddIn Manager Is Blank

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm unable to remove addins in MS Visual Studio.Net 2008 since the Addin Manager is blank.

Running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable without opening Visual Studio, 
   1.      Delete the .Addin XML registration file for the add-in that you want to remove.

```
  The default location is <drive>:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins.
```

2.      At a Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt, type devenv /resetaddin Namespace.ClassName, where Namespace and Classname are replaced with the name of your add-in project and its class name, respectively. For example, devenv /resetaddin MyAddin1.Connect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228765(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the add-in manager window is blank, then there are no running add-ins.

If you wish to disable all add-ins, then look in Tools->Options > Addin and Macro security, and disable them there.

If you wish to uninstall any add-ins, and you can't find specific uninstallers in the usual places (control panel or start menu) then look in the Addin and Macro security page to see the paths that Visual Studio searches for its add-ins. Look in each location and (carefully) remove any *.Addin files that represent add-ins you wish to remove. A good approach is to move them out of the folder (rather than deleting them) so you can easily recover them if you decide you didn't want to remove something.

Comment: If you go the folders, changing extension is sufficient and allows a rollback in case of mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to remove the .addin file and then perform the devenv /resetins. it is applicable for VS 2005, 2008 and 2010.